# I have a Static Void Main in c# but keep getting the CS5001 Error

Tags: c#, static, program-entry-point, void

This is the most basic code there is. I'm working in visual studio 17.5.4, ASP.NET is 17.5.318.41597.

Im not new to programming but I'm new to c# and visual studio so I dunno if there is some weird setting or something I am not seeing.

```
using System;

class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Comment: do you create console app?

Comment: I certainly can't reproduce this. Is there anything else in your project? What's in your project file? Is that really the code you're trying to compile?

Comment: The issue was the type of project it was, I can't remember what the type was in the project I was trying to run this code, but I had to use the windows console app project type.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the solution manager tab and then right-click on the application and properties, then try to change put the class as initialization object.